# Building a custom object in powershell (Add-Member)

Tags: powershell, loops, object

Trying to build a custom object inside a For-EachObject loop.

Here is the code

```
$infouser =  New-Object -TypeName psobject 

(Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$poste\C$\Users").Name | ForEach-Object {

$nomcomplet += Get-ADUser -Identity $_ | select-object -ExpandProperty userprincipalname 

Add-Member -InputObject $infouser -Name "Code" -Value $_ -MemberType NoteProperty
Add-Member -InputObject $infouser -Name "Nom complet" -Value $nomcomplet -MemberType NoteProperty

}


$infouser | Out-GridView
```

What i'm trying to achieve is a custom object containing the usernames in C:\USERS along with their equivalent full e-mail adress from the AD.

What I have works partially, it displays the first one it can add, but it doesn't "append" the others : [image]

Giving the error : "Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name...because a member with that name already exists. If you want to overwrite the member anyway, use the Force parameter to overwrite it."

I don't want to overwrite, I want to append it to the object so the final object contains all usernames and all adresses.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: You should use a array of custom objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an array of psobjects, not a single psobject. You're creating a single object and re-adding the properties X times.

This implicitly creates an array and adds a new psobject for each loop.

```
$infouser = (Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$poste\C$\Users").Name | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        'Code' = $_
        'Nom Complet' = $(Get-ADUser -Identity $_ | select-object -ExpandProperty userprincipalname )
    }
}

$infouser | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Ahh great. I knew my logic was wrong, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Love the use of $() instead of additing results to a variable, much more concise